# does jest have a --require command like mocha

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Does Jest have a similar option like mocha's `--require`? I would prefer to have an option like `--require` in the command line rather than putting a `require(x)` in the title of every file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Jest` configuration provides [`setupFiles`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfiles-array) and [`setupTestFrameworkScriptFile`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setuptestframeworkscriptfile-string) which can be used to run setup code before tests run.

The `require(x)` statement would need to perform all of the needed side-effects, there isn't a way to access the module exports of `x` from a `require` statement in the setup file, but it looks like [that is exactly how the --require option works in Mocha](https://mochajs.org/#-r---require-module-name).

Just create a setup file that calls `require(x)` and either add it to the `Jest` config using one of the two options listed above or [pass it on the command line using the `--setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` option](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#setuptestframeworkscriptfile-file)